# How do I access properties of a popup that is defined in a style (WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, xceed

I have a timePicker from WPF using the Xceed Toolkit. The ListBox to select the time is displayed as a popup. The ToggleButton shown below opens and closes the Popup. Clicking *outside* the Popup also closes it, thanks to StaysOpen. What I want is to close the popup when I make a selection. I am trying with codebehind, but if there is an easy way to do it with XAML, I'd try that too.

The file where the Popup is defined is App.xaml. I reference TimePickerStyle from a view, called ExampleView.xaml.

ExampleView.xaml

```
<toolkit:TimePicker x:Name="tp"
         Grid.Column="2" Kind="Local" 
         Background="White" 
         Value="{Binding ReminderTime, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Style="{StaticResource TimePickerStyle}"  
         TextBoxBase.TextChanged = "DateTimePicker_ValueChanged"  
                                            />
```

I try to access the Popup from the Codebehind, but for the life of me cannot figure it out.

ExampleView.xaml.cs

```
private void DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       // This is where I tried to close the popup, but I can't figure out how to access
       //     it. I don't get a visual tree here
       // tp.Style.Popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="TimePickerStyle"

<Setter Property="Template">
...

                <ToggleButton x:Name="_timePickerToggleButton"
                                              Grid.Column="1"
                                              Style="{StaticResource TimeToggleButtonStyle}"
                                              IsTabStop="{TemplateBinding IsTabStop}"
                                              BorderThickness="0">
                                    <ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                        <Binding Path="IsOpen"
                                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                            <Binding.Converter>
                                                <toolkit:InverseBoolConverter />
                                            </Binding.Converter>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                    <ToggleButton.IsEnabled>
                                        <Binding Path="IsReadOnly"
                                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                            <Binding.Converter>
                                                <toolkit:InverseBoolConverter />
                                            </Binding.Converter>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </ToggleButton.IsEnabled>

                                    <ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Path SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                                  Focusable="False" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                
                                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popupx"
                                       AllowsTransparency="True"
                                       IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_timePickerToggleButton}"
                                       StaysOpen="False"
                                       ToolTip="">
                                    
                                    
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0"
                                            MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                                            MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=root}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource TransparentScroller}"
                                                <ListBox x:Name="PART_TimeListItems"
                                                         BorderThickness="0"
                                                         DisplayMemberPath="Display"
                                                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                        <extensionProperties:ScrollParentWhenAtMax />
                                                    
                                                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                            <Setter Property="Padding"
                                                                    Value="4,3" />
                                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">                                                                   
                                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                            <MultiTrigger>
                                                                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                                                                               Value="True" />
                                                                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                                                                               Value="False" />
                                                                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                                                        Value="{DynamicResource WorkflowColor2}" />
                                                                            </MultiTrigger>
                                                                            <MultiTrigger>
                                                                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                                                                               Value="False" />
                                                                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                                                                               Value="True" />
                                                                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                                                        Value="{DynamicResource SelectedColor}" />
                                                                            </MultiTrigger>
                                                                            <MultiTrigger>
                                                                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                                                                               Value="True" />
                                                                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                                                                               Value="True" />
                                                                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                                                        Value="{DynamicResource WorkflowColor2}" />
                                                                            </MultiTrigger>
                                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                                </ListBox>
                                            </ScrollViewer>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Popup>
```

More Readable version of App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="TimePickerStyle"

<Setter Property="Template">
...

    <ToggleButton x:Name="_timePickerToggleButton"> ... </ToggleButton>
                                
    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popupx"
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_timePickerToggleButton}"
           StaysOpen="False"
           ToolTip="">
                                    
                                    
          <Border>
                <Grid>
                     <ScrollViewer>
                            <ListBox x:Name="PART_TimeListItems">
                                   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                           <Setter Property="Template" 
                                                 <Setter.Value>
                                                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                         ...         
                                                         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                         ...
                                     </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                             </ListBox>
                       </ScrollViewer>
                 </Grid>
            </Border>
     </Popup>
```

I tried accessing the Popup via codebehind, but can't find it. I can get the style, but then the popup element is nowhere to be found. I also tried setting a trigger on Popup, but I'm not well-versed in XAML, and that gave me a dead end. I was also thinking about adding more complex logic into the IsOpen binding, but don't know how to have it look at the ToggleButton at the same time as it's listening for a ListBox OnSelectionChanged.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what it looks like from the codebehind when I try to find it via the debugger. It is listed in ChildNames, but I can't figure out how to modify it from there.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You are styling a `TimePicker` object.  What is that?  Who makes it?  If that PART_Popup is truly a normal element and (i.e. not your invention), there is a chance that it might expose it as a public member of the TimePicker that you could just access.  If not, you can use the `VisualTreeHelper` to try to get at the first child of the `TimePicker` you find of type `Popup`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can't find it as a public member. I can find the setters inside Style. Inside that, I can find the template, and the triggers inside the template. At that point though, I hit a dead end. VisualTree is null for whatever reason.

Comment: Who makes the `TimePicker`?  Try looking at its structure in the the debugger (run a Debug Build) in the  Visual Studio Visual Tree Window.  Do you see the Popup there or anything around it?

Comment: TimePicker comes from Xceed. 
https://doc.xceed.com/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.TimePicker_properties.html

I just added an image of me trying to find the popup using the debugger. It doesn't seem like I can get anything near Popup. The closest I get are the triggers which are on the same level.

Comment: I can see it in ChildNames though, just not access it.

Comment: Wait until it is loaded.  Put an event handler on its `Loaded` event and then look at the visual tree there

Comment: I added another image to the original. I can now see it in my visual tree. I still haven't been able to access it via code. (tp.Template works, but I can't access tp.Template.root.PART_Popup).

Your advice has already been very helpful though in helping me learn the structure of all this code. Thank you so much.

Comment: You should be using mvvm and binding. Then you wouldn't need to worry about finding ui elements. You'd have an isopen property and selectedtime property. You could set isopen false from the setter of selectedtime.

Comment: I'm all for @Andy's suggestion.  If there is a `DependencyProperty` you can bind to named `IsOpen`, then by all means, do that.  I just am not familiar with the control itself.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.isopen?view=windowsdesktop-6.0